# The best way to retain an apostrophe when filtering with filter_var

Tags: php, validation, filtering

I have users with apostrophe's in their names, e.g. Martin O'Loughlin.  I want to be able to filter and validate without using a framework, so am relying on the `filter_var` function.

Is there a more efficient way to handle apostrophes with `filter_var`, than this:

```
$name = "Martin O'Loughlin";
$name = filter_var(filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
```

EDIT:
As a supplementary point, if you need to apply two filters (as in the case above), can you do it with filter_var_array?  Or not?

Comment: Filter and validate for what?

Comment: I want to store in in a database, and later display it in a view.

Comment: Use a DB specific escaping then, or parametrized queries (PDO for example)